# Wlan/wifi missing in Toshiba P50-C-11V laptop

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, bios

I am helping a friend fix his computer but I have been battling with the problem for over 5hours.

It's a Toshiba Satellite laptop, model P50-C-11v

The wifi icon is not displayed on the taskbar.

It is not found when searched for.

No WLAN driver. Once downloaded and installed, it doesn't appear.

I have go fo gpedit.msc to enable and disable the “remove icon…”, and reverted to its initial stage. None could fix it.

I have gone to services as an administrator to start the WLAN manager, WLAN Autoconfig, and wifi manager, and restarted the system, to no avail.

I went to bios settings, entered advanced settings and security, I couldn't find anything related to wifi or WLAN there which is not enabled. I saw LAN and it's enabled.

I solved a similar problem on a Lenovo system through the Bios settings, I enabled the i/o port access under security there but I am finding it hard to solve the same issue on Toshiba.

Running Windows Update Assistant did not solve it.

Resetting the system did not solve it.

I went to device manager and selected show hidden drivers. I found the WLAN driver there. I scanned the network adapter for hardware changes, reset the system but still can't find the wifi or WLAN connection in the system.

I need help here please.[see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOWOY.jpg)

Laptop model: Toshiba P50-C-11V.

.......
OS: Windows 10 pro version 21H1

Comment: Try a USB Wireless card and see if that works. It appears the inside wireless card may have a hardware issue (unseated or defective).

Comment: Testing it with a Linux live media would also be a good idea.

Comment: The system recognises the external USB wireless card but it still doesn't work. The wifi still doesn't show. Any clue how I can access his NIC in the bios?

Comment: @gronostaj, please how do I go about that?

Comment: Download a [Ubuntu ISO](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=20.04.2.0&architecture=amd64) and write it to a flash drive using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/). Boot from it. Check if WiFi works.

Comment: @John, a situation the external USB driver doesn't show wifi, what do you think could be the problem?

Comment: If the USB card shows up and then per the post by @gronostaj to try Ubuntu works with the internal card, then you may wish to try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.